# How to ensure all Side-Threads(Different Class) closed when Closing Main Window

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a main form class in C# and a side-class. I am creating instances of side-class and calling a method of that class from that instance. That method starts new thread. Now I am creating multiple instances and calling methods for each of them. So, multiple threads are started. Now I have implemented a method in side-class to ensure the thread is closed when going out from the method associated with the thread.
I don't know if a user suddenly clicks the X(close) button of the main frame window, then how to handle the threads which are inside that side-class.

P.S - The side-class's instances are instantiated within a method of the main form class. So, at the time of disposing, I don't have the instances with me, so that I can stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by closing the Main window you are terminating the application, then you can just set IsBackground to true in you worker threads, in the side-classes, when you create them. As so:

```
    var newThread = new Thread(DoWork) {IsBackground = true};
    newThread.Start();
```

However, if closing your 'Main' window is not the end of the application, then the Main window should keep an array of references to the instantiated side-classes. It should then dispose/ set a flag on each side instance to signal that the thread should stop (how you do this is up to you -  a flag periodically checked in the side-class might be appropriate). This call should happen in the OnClose of the 'Main' window.

Comment: I am trying to terminate the application when the cross(x) button would be clicked and at the same time I want to stop the Threads those are running on another class' methods.
As you said I think that can be done only by enabling a flag at the Main Form Class when it's `dispose`ing and to check continuously if the flag is changed in the side-class. if changed, then stop that thread.

Comment: In that case, as I suggested, can you not just set the IsBackground flag to true when you create the Threads in the side-class? The runtime will then terminate those threads for you when the foreground threads finish.

Comment: Okay. done and worked. Thank you. So, this property tells the OS to terminate the Threads as soon as the Main thread ends. As they are background threads. Right?

Comment: Yes, correct. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could set the side-threads to BackGroundWorkers which close when the application ends.
Or in the form.Closing event call their respective join() methods.
This will let the application wait untill the threads are finished.

Comment: I have not implemented BackGroundWorkers. I am only working with simple Threads.

And I cannot call their join() methods. As the threads are inside another side-class. and the objects of the class are instantiated within a method. So, the objects are not accessible from Form Closing event. Any other way?

Comment: it would help if you could post some code so it would be possible to answer more accurately ;)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible to summarize it.

Comment: last thing you could try then, is in the side class make a public void jointhreads() {thread.join(); thread2.join(); etc etc }  
And call this in the mainform.closing event. Without code I can't be more specific I'm afraid. Good luck